# Can't access data from database after code files in public_html is restored

Tags: php, mysql

Unfortunately My public_html was removed from server. I push my Backup code into public_html through file Zilla but it is showing an error like Cannot Access to database

Database admin name and Passwords are same.

Comment: What is the exact error? Are you also pointing to the correct database? You might have your backup pointing to your localhost, which of course wouldn't work on your host. You could try to include you connection string as well (leave out the user and pass of course).

Comment: I am pointing to the correct Database and my credentials are Correct.

Comment: Is there any issue with .mysql_backup file

Comment: Include the full error please. Hard to determine from 'cannot access to database'.

Comment: ok i Will explain the Scenario ..... After my code was deleted i replace the public_html folder with my Backup Data..  Databases are not effected. Simply i replace my connect.php file with my Credentials.When i try to access my website it is showing an error like "Cannot connect to the database!"

Comment: Try to add this line after your `mysqli_connect()`;  `or die(mysqli_error());` and let me know what it outputs. The string should look like this `mysqli_connect("","","","") or die(mysqli_error());`

Comment: I am getting the same Error

Comment: Ait, then I'm definitive gonna need some more information. First off, double check that the parameters in your `mysqli_connect()` corresponds to the information that you have gotten from your host. What are the link to your site? Are you creating a variable with the connection, something like; `$conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");` and is this variable being overwritten at later point in your code?

Comment: And also, we are in an agreement that you connection string is as followed; `mysqli_connect("HOST_ADDRESS", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DATABASE");`, right?

Comment: yes all credentials are right

Comment: [22-Jul-2017 13:19:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/qrcpub/public_html/agriconference.org/test/jaksdjkas.php on line 7
[22-Jul-2017 13:24:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PDO' not found in /home/qrcpub/public_html/agriconference.org/test/jaksdjkas.php on line 8
[22-Jul-2017 13:28:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/qrcpub/public_html/agriconference.org/test/jaksdjkas.php on line 6

Comment: mysql_connect , pdo , mysqli_connect three are not working

Comment: "Call to undefined function": PHP is essentially telling you it doesn't have the function that you call. I.e. your PHP has either been compiled not to have those extensions and/or they aren't being loaded dynamically. Hard to tell you as we have no clue how your PHP was installed. Try seeing in the output of `phpinfo()` which modules are available.

Answer (score 0):

From the description it seems you have a problem with the mysql extenstion. Do the same with PDO Check whether [it is installed to your PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php). If it turns out that you have MySQL extension and PDO, then the problem is probably that a variable does not have the value you expect and, like a PDO statement having a value of false. If this is the case, then it is quite possible that your folder structure was not restored correctly.